# Graphs goes out of the assigned div container

Tags: mxgraph

I am trying to show some graphs designed with draw.io editor in a totally separated page where, through mxGraph, I parse the xml file saved from draw.io and render it inside a  element.

```
<div class="graph-details" id="<portlet:namespace/>graph-details" >
   <div class="graph-container" id="<portlet:namespace/>graph"></div>
</div>
```

My code is

```
var container = document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace/>graph');
var graph = new mxGraph(container);
var diagram = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
var codec = new mxCodec(diagram);
codec.decode(diagram.documentElement, graph.getModel());
graph.fit();
```

The problem arise when the graph is big, the graph.fit() function seems not to be able to reduce it to stay inside my DIV so the generated  element goes out of the DIV, overlapping it and other elements in page.
[image: diagram out of div]

What could be the problem? I noticed that in this situations the svg element has a min-width property much bigger than the parent .
If the diagram is small enough the behavior is correct and it gets cropped if I try to drag it out of the div.

thanks in advance
Marco

Comment: have you tried adding a breakpoint in mxGraph.js source and understand why it doesn't get the size of your div ?

Comment: mxGraph is really flexible but my rule of thumb is: don't even try to do stuffs at the svg level. There is always a solution in the API!

Comment: @Colin No, I haven't tried (mainly because a metter of time) but I solved the problem as detailed in my answer, unfortunately I had to break your rule, sorry! :-) Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was two different problems:

1) The fit() api wasn't working because the DIV element didn't have the correct Width and Height when fit() function was invoked, so I pre-calculate the correct dimensions for the DIV before calling graph.fit(). Now all diagrams are rendered at the best zoom factor to fit them in page and this also solved some cross-browsers rendering differences.

2) I  workarounded the overlapping misbehavior with a bit of code to adjust the  element's
minWidth and minHeight properties to "fit-content" value:

```
var svg=document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
if (svg!=undefined && svg!=null) {
    svg[0].style.minWidth='fit-content';
    svg[0].style.minHeight='fit-content';
}
```